# Cannot create askPassword user with scim2

Tags: java, wso2, scim2, wso2-identity-server

Hi I use wso2is version 5.4.1 as identity server.

I want to create user using scim2 api. 
When user is created, an email is sent to the user and he will be able to click on a link recieved in email and through the link he will be able to change password - that is what I mean with askPassword user as specified here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS541/Creating+Users+Using+the+Ask+Password+Option

**First option (WORKS) how to create user using WSO2 managment console**

[image]

This scenario works and email is sent.

**Second option (DOESN'T WORK) how to create user using SCIM2**

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data {"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"Smith","givenName":"Paul"},"userName":"Test","password":"password","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"Test@abc.com","type":"home"},{"value":"paulSmith@abc.com","type":"work"}],"EnterpriseUser":{askPassword:"true"}} --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://mylink:port/scim2/Users
```

Wso2is console outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for version 5.6.0. It is necessary to to fill proper property for email address...  **{"value":"email@gmail.com"}** if this is not set, then I get error :  *Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block*

```
{"schemas":[],
 "name":{"familyName":"Smith","givenName":"Paul"},
 "userName":"test110",
 "password":"password",
 "emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"email@gmail.com","type":"home"}, 
           {"value":"email@gmail.com","type":"work"},
           {"value":"email@gmail.com"}],
 "EnterpriseUser":{"askPassword":"true"},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the askPassword attribute within double quoation marks.

e.g

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data {"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"Smith","givenName":"Paul"},"userName":"Test","password":"password","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"Test@abc.com","type":"home"},{"value":"paulSmith@abc.com","type":"work"}],"EnterpriseUser":{"askPassword":"true"}} --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://mylink:port/scim2/Users
```

Please check with the above request.

If the above does not work check whether the following property is available in {Server_Home}/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml file under < EventListeners> tag

```
<Property name="Data.Store">org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.store.JDBCIdentityDataStore</Property
```

Comment: No, this is not problem, even if I had it with quotes still the same response and btw... it would throw different error.

Comment: can you post the full console log with stack-trace?

Comment: Also check whether the following property is there in <Server_Home>/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml file under <EventListeners> tag ..           



<Property name="Data.Store">org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.store.JDBCIdentityDataStore</Property>